# iOS: OpenCV Red color range

Tags: ios, opencv, bgr

I am trying to encircle Red color in the picture using OpenCV library. I have seen many question in google but no one helped for me. My code is below:

```
void highLightRed(const cv::Mat& inputFrame, cv::Mat& outputFrame)
{
cv::Mat gray, edges, red, blurred;

// blur will enhance edge detection
medianBlur(inputFrame, blurred, 9);

// give image in gray color space
getGray(blurred, gray);

cv::inRange(gray, cv::Scalar(0,0,112), cv::Scalar(60,0,225), red); //BGR

// using Canny algorithm to find edges
cv::Canny(red, edges, 50, 150);

std::vector< std::vector<cv::Point> > c;

// find contours of edges
cv::findContours(edges, c, cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

NSLog(@"size: %lu", c.size());

inputFrame.copyTo(outputFrame);

// draw contour in green (0,200,0) with thinkness 3
//cv::drawContours(outputFrame, c, -1, cv::Scalar(0,200,0),3);
cv::drawContours(outputFrame, c, -1, cv::Scalar(0,200,0),2);

}

void getGray(const cv::Mat& input, cv::Mat& gray)
{
const int numChannes = input.channels();

if (numChannes == 4)
{
    cv::cvtColor(input, gray, cv::COLOR_BGRA2GRAY);
}
}
```

Problem: This code works perfect if only Red and white color are there in picture, it encircles red color successfully. But if multiple colors specially dark colors are involved the color detection fails.
I need exact range which only detect Red color. Thanks

Comment: As @skm told, you better switch to HSV color space. You don't need to split and merge the channels, but you can use `cv::inRange`.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31281725/5008845) for an example.

Comment: I already played a lot with cv::inRange but i did not succeeded to find proper range. And switching to HSV color space was a better idea.

Comment: If you find that @skm answer is good, please consider to upvote or mark as an answer. If you didn't manage to solve your issue, please tell us what's wrong. If you solved it by yourself, post an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Finding the exact range of color in BGR or RGB format is very difficult. You will have to play around it a lot (if you are a newbie).

A very simple way:

1. Convert your image into HSV format using `cvtColor()`
2. Split your `HSV image` into three channel i.e. H, S and V-channel.
3. Extract the red color from the `H-channel`. You can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737613/image-of-hsv-color-wheel-for-opencv) to find the hue range of Red color.
4. Merge this new `H-channel` with the old `S` and `V` channel.
5. Convert back to BGR format. Now your BGR image will contain only the Red color.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
You put me in the right direction. Actually i needed the original image with boundary around red color so step 4 and 5 did not help in my case.
For the time being I managed to fix by removing all contour points which were not Red from the list returned by above code.