# What is the correct hsv range for this image?

Tags: c++, opencv, hsv

I am trying to use inrange function in opencv to get the square(green part) but it doesn't seems to work. Here is my image
[image]
Here is my code:

```
cv::inRange(src, cv::Scalar(35, 20, 20), cv::Scalar(85, 255, 200), src);
```

And here is the output for my code:
[image]

How can i get  all the green part using correct hsv values....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the HSV color wheel and pick the right range. Be aware that **HSV** has  fit into 3 8 bit- channels, but the **H** channel does not, so you have to divide this value by 2. The range for **H** is 0-180 in OpenCV. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737613/image-of-hsv-color-wheel-for-opencv) for reference. 
[image: HSV color wheel]

With this configuration ( I tested the values with ImageJ not OpenCV)

```
cv::inRange(src, cv::Scalar(35, 60, 200), cv::Scalar(60, 255, 255), src);
```

i got this result:
[image]
With `cv::findContours` you can easily detect all contours and filter just the square by shape and size or by their hierarchy.

Comment: I tried that before, but it didn't seemed to work because i didn't knew about H[0-180]. Thanks